# CMS Recommendations for Auto Dealership

Tags: content-management-system

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105509/open-source-cms-pre-designed-for-auto-dealer) but there wasn't any positive answer.

I am trying to help a friend to build a car dealer web page like [Fantasy Junction](http://www.fantasyjunction.com/). 

I think they use *CakePHP* plus *jQuery lightBox plugin*.

So far I am thinking of either *ModX CMS* or *Expression Engine*.

My friend and I are not web developers, so something simple would be nice. This will also help because I've been thinking about learning a web framework. But there are so many! I don't want to pick up something that will be totally useless and cumbersome.

*Any recommendation that will help the learning process would be great!*

Answer (score 0):

Try jT CarFramework (http://intersofts.com). It's a free solution and has online demo so you can check it out if it fits your needs.